# sqlplus cannot spool a file whose name starts with a dot on windows

Tags: windows, filenames, sqlplus, spool

I'm using some windows scripts involving spooling files with sqlplus. I keep getting the error:

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Z:/regression/RBC/.flashback"
```

I was able to limit the issue to a rather small scope: I cannot spool some files  whose name start with a dot in windows. In windows cmd, I entered sqlplus with

```
sqlplus /nolog
```

Then tried the following commands:

```
SQL> spool Z:/regression/test
SQL> spool Z:/regression/test.txt
SQL> spool Z:/regression/.test
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Z:/regression/.test"
SQL> spool Z:/regression/.test.
SQL> spool Z:/regression/.test.txt
```

Strange enough, only `.test` fails. But it is right what I need. I tried the same commands in Linux, there is no problem. I'm using sqlplus 11.2.0.3.0 on windows. What's more strange, on my colleague's machine it works totally fine. (Actually the scripts are used by all developers in my company.) Seems I've unfortunately met the nightmare for coders: irreproducible bug...

Anyway I got completely stuck here. Has this ever happened to anyone? What are possible approaches that I can take?

Comment: you canNOT compare linux to windows. They're entirely different operating systems, and the fact that a filename works in linux is utterly irrelevant to Windows. Windows is pretty schizophrenic. Explorer doesn't let you create a `.name` file, but you can easily do so from the command prompt. You're probably getting nailed by that somehow.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the comment. Yes I'm aware of that. By "irreproducible" I not only mean that what works on Linux fails in Windows, but also that what works on other people's Windows machine fails on mine...I believe it involves some config to do, I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: It may be a permissions problem.  The other `.test` files that follow spool successfully, correct?

Comment: @tale852150 Yes, the only situation in which it fails is when the file name I want to spool is a dot plus some characters. How can this be related to permission problem? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle docs, description of cause of error:

**Cause:** The STORE command was unable to create the specified file. There may be insufficient disk space, too many open files, or read-only protection on the output directory.

Based on what you have shown in the question, the last option is not an issue.
Check the other two scenarios -- insufficient disk space and too many open files.

I was able to SPOOL to a `.test` file on my system using Oracle XE 11.2.0.2:

[image]